# if statement within a ng-repeat directive on Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement an if into a ng-repeat directive but I am having a hard time. my code which work for now is:

```
<p ng-repeat="list in lists">{{list[id].title}}</p>
```

What I want to do is basically

```
<p ng-repeat="list in lists if list[id].selected">{{list[id].title}}</p>
```

Of course, on the second line I am getting an error. Any advice on this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know Angular, but from what I've read, you probably could achieve that by using filters.

Comment: I did some study with a filter to show or not. I could do it with ng-switc, ng-show and ng-hide. The problem is that this would add a ton of stuff to my html, something that I don't know, once it's a huge list. @yabol

Answer (score 34):

As I wrote in a comment, you could use filters to achieve that. Here's example: http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/ZfGx4/44/

```
ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:myFilter"
```

And filter code:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(item) {
    return item.selected == true;
};
```

**Edit:**
I found that it is possible to do it with inline filter like this:

```
ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:{selected: true}"
```

Comment: I see fiddle removed and shows 404. please update the link.

Answer (score 10):

What you need to add here is a filter:

```
<p ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:{selected:true}">test {{list.title}}</p>
```

I've added [a plnkr as an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQGx2FA8VwTYlC3zHFQT?p=preview).